# Play with numbers

Tags: number-theory

Find three  numbers whose sum is equal to their products. (1,2,3 are  those numbers)
Now My question is how to find these numbers? (Is this information sufficient to apply some mathematics to it and get answer?)

Comment: $-1, 0,1$? $-3,-2,-1$?

Comment: Real numbers, integer numbers, natural numbers?

Comment: natural numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we have 3 consecutive numbers, we call them
$$n , n+1, n+2$$
We want their sum to be equal to their product
$$n + (n+1) + (n+2) = n (n+1)(n+2)$$
$$3n+3 = n^3+3n^2+2n$$

$$n^3+3n^2-n-3=0$$
Solving the polynomial above

$$n^3+3n^2-n-3=(n-1)(n+1)(n+3)=0$$
The roots of the polynomial are
$$x=-3,x=-1,x=1$$
Therefore we have three sequence whose sum equal to their product
$$-3,-2,-1$$
$$-1,0,1$$
$$1,2,3$$

Comment: The OP does not require consecutive numbers.

Comment: my mistake, looks like yours solution is better @lhf

Comment: In the case of consecutive numbers, it's simpler to consider $n-1,n,n+1$, which gives $3n=n^3-n$.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution assuming natural numbers.

Let the numbers be $x \le y \le z$. Then $xyz = x+y+z\le 3z$ implies $xyz \le 3z$.

If $z=0$, then $x=y=z=0$.

If $z\ne 0$, then $xy \le 3$ and so there are only a small number of candidates for $(x,y)$.

Only $x=1$ and $y=2$ work with $xyz = x+y+z$, and give $z=3$.

Comment: Sir, by that condition xy<3, we can consider x=-4 and y=3. then?

Comment: @TanviSorout, you said *natural* numbers in the comments...

Comment: OK, I got that in case of natural no. Sir but what would be the changes in your ans assumptions if it would be integers case

Comment: @TanviSorout, please clarify your original question then.